# 「bun install」failure to establish correct symbolic links

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, node-modules, bun

I'm having a problem with `bun`: the symbolic links in the .node_modules/.bin directory are not created correctly!

take `stylelint` as an example:

[image]

Running `bun run stylelint` gives the following result:

```bash
/bin/bash: ./node_modules/.bin/stylelint: No such file or directory
```

bun version is 1.0.0

Expectation: correct symbolic links established and functioning